# AutoMapper Let Instance Variable

Tags: c#, automapper, dto

Apologies if this has been asked before, I'm not sure of the specific terms to ask.

**A short example:**

```
public class SignOffDetails
{
    public int fUserID {get; set;}
    public DateTime SignedAt {get; set;}
}

public class User
{
    public int UserID {get; set;}
    public string FullName {get; set;}
    public Image Signature {get; set;}
}

public class MdlsCombined
{
    public int UserID {get; set;}
    public string FullName {get; set;}
    public Image Signature {get; set;} 
}

public void Program 
{

    Mapper.CreateMap<SignOffDetails, MdlsCombined>()
        .ForMember(m => m.UserID, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.fUserID));
    // Awesome
}
```

I know I can just map them individually, but is there a function to do the following that I haven't yet discovered?

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SignOffDetails, MdlsCombined>()
    .Let(z => (User)Users.GetUser(z.fUserID))
    .ForMember(m => m.UserID, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.fUserID))
    .ForMember(m => m.FullName, y => y.MapFromLet(l => ((User)l).FullName))
    .ForMember(m => m.Signature, y => y.MapFromLet(l => ((User)l).Signature));
```

I realize this is quite silly and kinda removes the whole point of procedural programming in the first place, but it's still a legit use imho.

The actual solution is to have two maps from SignOffDetails > MdlsCombined and User > MdlsCombined, but that ain't fluent ;)

Comment: Maybe you should rephrase the question. I'm not sure what your question is about

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you're trying to map 2 objects (`SignOffDetails` and `User`) into one (`MdlsCombined`)? AutoMapper doesn't support this natively (as its not a 1-1 mapping) but you could potentially do something with `AfterMap`. Although I think that you will still eventually end up with multiple mappings.

Comment: I actually want the same thing!